# Can I get Steam to stop annoying me with notifications that I've earned a nickel?

Tags: steam

Steam has trading cards. Great. Now I have a bunch of nigh-worthless digital bits to get rid of.

Fortunately, the Market provides an easy way to do that! I can recoup pennies on the dollar from the cost of my poor choices during a given Steam sale by selling the trading cards!

However, since they're only worth a nickel or three, I don't really care that any given card has sold. I *do* however, want to know when the occasional valuable item sells for a buck or three, and I also don't want to just blacklist the email address to my spam folder, because it's the same address that Important Things like receipts for my ill-advised purchases comes from.

Is there any way to get Steam to throttle these notifications so that my phone will stop beeping every 9 seconds with a notification that my FTL card that I never cared about has sold for 12 cents?

Comment: There may be a way to stop these mails entirely, but not at this level of granularity. At least, not that I know of.

Comment: @Nolonar A filter that deletes mails with a certain headline is pretty simple and does not require any special "granularity".

Comment: Easy answer is to stop putting nickle-priced items on the market.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness True, but in that case this question would be better off at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) rather than here.

Comment: @Nolonar: Asking how to filter out certain emails would probably be for [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or SU, but asking if it's possible at all is fine. Answers don't define the question.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid there's no way to opt out of these recipt emails from Steam. However, if you use Gmail, you can create a filter.

Click **⚙** > *Settings*
[image: Gear > Settings]

*Filters* tab > *Create a new filter*
[image: Create a new filter]

Put `noreply@steampowered.com` in the *From* field and `You have sold an item on the Community Market` in the *Subject* field then click *Create filter with this search*
[image: Create filter with this search]

Finally, if you wish to archive but not delete it, check *Skip the Inbox (Archive it)* and then click *Create Filter*
[image: Skip the Inbox, Create Filter]

Answer (score 4):

I checked out the [email preferences page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/emailoptout). According to it, even if you opt-out of all email marketing communication, you will still receive "**purchase receipts**, Steam Guard access codes, and other account-related notifications." So I don't think it's possible to disable them.

As an alternative to disabling them directly though, you could probably configure your email account to automatically delete them or mark them as read using [Gmail's filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters) or Outlook's rules on stuff with the subject "You have sold an item on the Community Market".

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter for emails from that address that have the words '$0.0' or $0. so that small purchases will be filtered. You can filter those below $0.10 or below $1.00 as you'd like. You could also set up additional filters from the same address if you want a certain granularity.

Comment: This doesn't work because a standard email receipt from Steam includes a Sales Tax line item of $0.00

Comment: Then filter specifically on the line that says how much the purchase was for and include the preceding text in the string. If you post the contents of such an email I can be more specific.

Comment: You'd probably just want the subject of "You have sold an item on the Community Market".